# Why is a userscript active on a given url in some browser but not another?

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

I develop a userscript to be used by a few people in my company. I advised them to install Tampermonkey. Someone complains that the script is not working for her: indeed, she has Tampermonkey installed, the userscript installed and active, and while the very same userscript was running fine on the very same URL for all people I talked so far, it is not triggered for that person (when clicking on the Tampermonkey icon, it says that Tampermonkey is active, but "no script is running").

I have no idea how to debug such a problem and whether this should be considered as a bug I should report to the Tampermonkey developing team: it is as if the URL were not matching the @include instruction (but it **is** matching for all other people that tried so far). Moreover, the script is triggered correctly for that person on some other URL where it should be triggered (so it is **not** like, for that person, the script is not working at all).

The URL is of the form `https://blabla.fr:4453/blabla/bla.jsp?blabla` and the userscript mentions `@include https://blabla.fr:4453/*`

Any suggestion on what to try to understand what is causing this behavior? Might it be related to the browser she uses?

Comment: Is she accessing using HTTPS as specified in your URL? Check that first. Next, I would also be curious if she has the same issue using the same browser (and roughly same version) as others not experiencing the issue. Additionally, is she running any other browser extensions which modify the page (i.e. other script injectors or ad-blockers)? I have personally never seen this during my TM dev days.

Comment: @JG7 : about https, the answer is yes. That is the first thing I checked. For the other questions, I do not know. I will have a look.

Comment: I guess the issue will remain a mystery: it was happening on a given browser (Firefox) and not with other browsers on the same computer. Removing the user script and re-installing it fixed the issue.

Comment: you may want to post this as an answer and mark the question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion given in comments, I post an answer to my own question. I did not figure out what was causing the issue, but removing the user-script and re-installing it fixed the problem.